# Excel to PDF, how to set landscape mode on PDF

Tags: vbscript

Below code works but I'm not sure where to put Landscape code below

```
Dim objXL
Set objXL = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
objXL.WorkBooks.Open ("C:\Users\MyUSer\Desktop\test1.xlsx") 
objXL.WorkBooks(1).Sheets("by CC").ExportAsFixedFormat 0, "C:\Users\H51516\Desktop\test1.pdf"
objXL.WorkBooks(1).Close False
Set objXL = nothing
```

Answer (score 0):

You can set the page orientation before exporting using the following:

```
Dim objXL
Set objXL = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
objXL.WorkBooks.Open ("C:\Users\MyUSer\Desktop\test1.xlsx") 
objXL.WorkBooks(1).Sheets("by CC").PageSetup.Orientation = xlLandscape
objXL.WorkBooks(1).Sheets("by CC").ExportAsFixedFormat 0, "C:\Users\H51516\Desktop\test1.pdf"
objXL.WorkBooks(1).Close False
Set objXL = nothing
```

Comment: Hey Matt,I got error "Unable to set the Orientation property of the PageSetup class"

Comment: According to Microsoft, this is due to not having print drivers installed? https://support.microsoft.com/en-gb/help/291298/you-cannot-use-page-setup-properties-in-excel-if-no-printers-were-installed